# Building electron on Linux/Jenkins returns cannot find name 'bigint' error

Tags: node.js, jenkins, electron

- Node: 12.18.4
- Electron: 7.1.2
- Electron-packager: 14.1.1
- Typescript: 3.1.6
- Jenkins: 2.176.4
- Angular 7

I have Angular-Electron project which trying to build on Jenkins.

Since yesterday my electron build started failing on Linux Ubuntu. It builds fine on Mac and Windows.

I get the following errors, Any idea why this error could happen?

```
ERROR in node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/fs.d.ts(2459,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/fs.d.ts(2463,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/fs.d.ts(2464,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/fs.d.ts(2465,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/fs.d.ts(2466,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(255,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(256,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(257,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(258,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(259,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(260,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(261,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(262,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(766,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'bigint'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/ts3.3/base.d.ts(13,21): error TS2727: Cannot find lib definition for 'esnext.bigint'. Did you mean 'esnext.intl'?
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts(119,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigInt64Array'.
node_modules/electron/node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts(120,57): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BigUint64Array'.
```